Calculus: Definition of a Plateau Point
What is the mathematical definition of a plateau point?  this came up in my calculus course, and it was described as a critical point where the first derivative's sign does not change from before or after it.
Another student said that the definition is when the first derivative and second derivative are both 0.
I started to get confused. Could anyone provide some clarity?  Are "plateau points" even an mathematical term?  I cannot find it in a calculus textbook (stewart) that I found online.

This makes me think of Undulation point, although I'm not certain you mean the same thing.

I haven't heard of a plateau point before but if it's a critical point that implies the first derivative is zero and if it doesn't change sign it implies the second derivative is also zero.

While the vanishing of first and second derivatives is necessary, it’s not sufficient. Consider $x^4$. It has vanishing first and second derivatives at $x=0$ but the first derivative changes sign as you go from negative to positive numbers.

Sounds like a made up term, but applied to something like $x^3$ it makes perfect sense.

@Randall: It sounds like a made-up term for someone who isn't aware of the term stationary point, a concept [and term] that historically has been much more significant [and used] in the calculus of variations and dynamical systems than in elementary calculus.

@DaveL.Renfro I interpret it differently.  The derivative not changing sign seems stricter than stationary.

@Randall: Yes, you're correct. I wasn't paying enough attention and overlooked that the OP is requiring there be no sign change. I used to call a point having this stronger property a terrace point -- see my answer to What is the Name of this Point?
